# how to add scroll-bar to windows store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am making an app for windows store; Like in c# we used Scroll bars to move down to the end of page and view all content, How can we do it for windows store? Like how to arrange data and use scroll bars to move to right and view all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't use `ScrollBar` controls directly and rather put your content in a `Panel` (usually `Grid/StackPanel/Canvas`) and put that panel inside of a `ScrollViewer`. Make sure to set `Horizontal/Vertical-Scroll-Mode/BarVisibility` and `ZoomMode` properties to match the direction of scrolling you want supported.

The benefit of using the `ScrollViewer` instead of `ScrollBar` is that you get smooth panning with touch that the platform handles for you with the Direct Manipulation layer that is not exposed to you in WinRT/XAML and also handles all the other inputs in a standard way.

Also if you are dealing with a list of items you want to scroll through, especially when the list is long - you would use some `ItemsControl` subclass - typically a vertical `ListView` for long, mostly text content lists or horizontal `GridView` for lists of richer media items. The benefit of using those is that they handle list virtualization for you - i.e. for lists of thousands of items you only get few item containers generated for the items currently visible in the control's view port and ones that are near the view port so they are ready when you scroll to them.

The templates of these list controls internally already have a `ScrollViewer` and the `ScrollViewer's` template has `ScrollBars` inside.

Comment: Thanks Filip, If I do it like                                     <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <image // SOME IMAGES WITH DEFINED SOURCE ADDED>
        </StackPanel> </ScrollViewer> IT STILL DOES'NT MOVE/SCROLL, Can you please focus on the error?

Comment: Your `ScrollViewer` is set up for vertical scrolling while your `StackPanel` expands horizontally. You'll need to set them up to do it one way.